# How can I bulk load this file into SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, geonames

I'm trying to import some data from the popular GeoNames site into SQL Server. It's a tab delimited text file. I didn't think there would be a problem but whatever I do, I just get an error message which says:

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 4. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

This is the file I'm trying to import:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin2Codes.txt

...and this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Admin2Codes](
    [code] [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
    [name] [NVARCHAR](200) NOT NULL,
    [asciiname] [NVARCHAR](200) NOT NULL,
    [geonameId] [INT] NOT NULL
)
```

I can't spot what the problem is. It works if I only have one row in the file, but as soon as there's more than one row, it fails. The line endings in the file appear to be \n and that matches my SQL:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Admin2Codes FROM 'D:\admin2codes.txt' 
WITH( 
   DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar', 
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
) 
 GO
```

Comment: Have you  already converted the admin2Codes.txt  from UTF-8 to UTF-16 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data uses the line feed as a row terminator that is used in UNIX instead of the carriage return and line feed used in windows. Try this instead:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+'''
```